# Magento - Display main categories

Tags: magento

I want to create a custom navigation bar to put in my header.phtml file.

For this I need a list of all the categories, i'm hoping that there is a simple function that I can call to get an array?

Comment: Googling `Magento Display main categories` gives me a lot of promising hits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following gets the subcategories of a specified category, you should be able to work from here I think:

```
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3); //this is cat 3, or can use: 
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$_categories = $_category->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description')) //or whatever fields you want
 ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
 ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
 ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
 ->joinUrlRewrite();
```

Then something like:

```
<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
```

etc...

You may also be interested in:

```
$this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl())
$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName())
$_category->getURL()
```

Hope that helps point you in the right direction. Clearly the `load(3)` can just be your root category.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think that I am getting somewhere now, although as this is going in my header.phtml file I am getting this issue where by if I click on the category the navigation changes to the sub categories of the category I am looking at. Sorry, im a magento noob. Thanks.

Comment: Good, but thinking a bit deeper: we're going to instantiate model in the view. Is there any other approach, via module for example? 
UPD: Yeap. This is the way it used to be. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code if you use single store or change the **$_rootCatId** as dynamic.

```
    $_rootCatId     = 2;
    $_rootCategory  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_rootCatId);
    $_catName       = $_rootCategory->getName();
    if($_rootCategory->hasChildren()) 
    {
        $_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')
                        ->joinUrlRewrite()
                        ->addIdFilter($_rootCategory->getChildren())
                        ->load();

        foreach($_collection AS $_sub)
        {
            $_subCat    = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_sub->getId());

            if($_subCat->hasChildren()) 
            {   
                echo '<li class="leve10 nav-'. $_subCat->getId() .'">';
                    echo '<a id="subCatLink">';
                        echo '<span>'. $this->htmlEscape($_subCat->getName()) .'</span>
                        </a>
                 </li>';
                echo '<ul id="subCatUl" class="no-display" style="padding:0px 13px;">';Categories();
                $__collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')
                        ->joinUrlRewrite()
                        ->addIdFilter($_subCat->getChildren())
                        ->load();

                foreach($__collection AS $__sub)
                {
                    $__subCat   = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($__sub->getId());
                    echo '<li class="leve20 nav-'. $__subCat->getId() .'">
                            <a href="'. $this->getCategoryUrl($__subCat) .'">
                             <span>'. $this->htmlEscape($__subCat->getName()) .'</span>
                            </a>
                         </li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<li class="leve10 nav-'. $_subCat->getId() .'">
                    <a href="'. $this->getCategoryUrl($_subCat) .'">
                     <span>'. $this->htmlEscape($_subCat->getName()) .'</span>
                    </a>
                 </li>';
            }
        }
    }
    else
        echo 'No Categories Found...';
```